# Extract only part of a frame that changed

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

Is it possible to output only the part of a frame that differs from the last frame as a png image with something like ffmpeg?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you only want the changed pixels and rest black?

Comment: Almost. It would be ideal if the background was transparent, but black would work too i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state, you want to "*output only the part of a frame that differs from the last frame*", you'll want the tblend filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in -filter_complex "format=yuva444p,split[diff][out];[diff]tblend=all_expr='if(eq(A,B),0,A)',geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='if(eq(lum(X,Y)+cb(X,Y)+cr(X,Y),0),0,255)',alphaextract[diff];[out]trim=start_frame=1[out];[out][diff]alphamerge" -vsync vfr out%d.png
```

The limitation is that if a pixel is originally `0` in both A and B, then that will be a false positive in the output.

Comment: I get the error "A luminance or RGB expression is mandatory". Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some pixel differencing. It's easier to do with a **For-loop** checking the pixels of both bitmaps (frames), Where `if same color = make transparent in output bitmap` and if not matching values (color) then `show as white in output bitmap`. This output bitmap could then be encoded as a new/next frame in the output video. But you didn't tell us about your programming language so no further advise on this method...

With just FFmpeg, you could try:

```
ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -i test2.mp4 -filter_complex "blend=all_mode=difference" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 out_difference.mp4
```

For some people it just gives green output (even for me), so if you find a fix for that issue (web research) then this is your solution. Other blend mode's like `"blend=all_mode=screen"` work fine

Comment: *it just gives green output* --> in YUV formats, `(0,0,0)` has a saturated chroma. Black will be `(0,128,128)`